# regex increment back reference by one

Tags: php, regex

I need to validate an input with the following pattern in php:

```
(4 digits)/(previous number + 1)
```

The first digit needs to be a 1 or a 2.

As an Example:

```
2018/2019 //valid
2000/2010 //invalid
1999/2000 //valid
2020/2019 //invalid
```

I've managed to get that both groups are equal, but I can't figure out how to increment the back reference by one...

```
/([1-2]\d{3})\/(\1)/
```

The `(\1)` needs to be incremented by one.

Is this possible with regex?

Comment: in my Laravel php project. I know I could split the string into two and check each side, but I thought it would be cool if I could do this with regex.

Comment: @Cid Thanks for pointing that out, the wording confused me. Let me check if there is an answer for that already. Certainly there is no way to increment the backreference in PHP, all one can do is match `'~(\d+)/(\d+)~'` and then see if `(int)$m[2] - (int)$m[1] == 1`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no worries, I thought that I was the one who needed coffee :).

Comment: Patrick, do you mean you have these strings as standalone strings? I'd use [this kind of code](https://3v4l.org/rBHLA) if they are not part of any longer strings.

Comment: I thing RegEx aren't the best technical choice for this purpose. `explode("/", $input);` and check `if ($result[1] == $result[0] + 1)` is far easier to read and maintain that going into some regular expression

Comment: Ok, I’ll explode the string. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Yeah, see https://3v4l.org/rBHLA. A regex can be used to prevalidate the strings though. Not sure you need that though. E.g. `if (preg_match('~^\d+/\d+\z~', $s)) {  /* PROCESS */ }`

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/A5g4e

Comment: Patrick, please let know what approach you actually need, with validation or not, if you still need an answer.

Comment: Your fiddle is what I needed. I would like to use this as Laravel validation Rule. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to first validate the string is in `<BOS><YEAR>/<YEAR><EOS>` format and then check if the second year is an incremented first year.

You may use `^([12]\d{3})/([12]\d{3})\z` regex (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fr4e8L/1)) to match and validate the string, and also capture the first year into Group 1 and the second year into Group 2.

Use

```
$strs  = ['2018/2019', '2000/2010','1999/2000','2020/2019', 'aaaa'];
foreach ($strs as $s) {
    if (preg_match('~^([12]\d{3})/([12]\d{3})\z~', $s, $m)) { 
        if ((int)$m[2] - (int)$m[1] == 1) {
            echo $s . " is valid!" . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo $s . " is NOT valid!" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    } else {
        echo $s . " is NOT valid!" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/06H8Q), output:

```
2018/2019 is valid!
2000/2010 is NOT valid!
1999/2000 is valid!
2020/2019 is NOT valid!
aaaa is NOT valid!
```